# How to bring C# AsQueryable() object into memory

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to use Entity Framework to pull a database list into memory with AsQueryable(), as when I use ToList() LINQ doesn't work anymore as it returns a list of 0 elements.

It is possible to do something like

```
var vwEntityList = dc.vwEntity.ToList().AsQueryable()
```

? I've tried this but LINQ fails when I query the object. If I use just .AsQueryable() it works but is really slow querying the database for every operation, which I want to avoid, I want to bring the EF view to memory as a queryable object.

When I have my list and try to use LINQ on it like

```
var newlist = vwEntityList.Where(x => x.deal_status == "B").ToList();
```

newlist is a list with 0 items, when I know there should be items in the list by running a similar query against the database, and it also works when using just .AsQueryable()

Thanks.

Comment: don't use `ToList` till the very end.

Comment: What do you mean by "LINQ doesn't work anymore" and "LINQ fails"?

Comment: If I understand your scenario, vwEntity is already IQueryable. `var myList = dc.vwEntity.ToList()` should materialize all entities in the corresponding table into memory (since you don't have any filtering methods in your query).

I'm confused though. You name your target variable `obj`, which implies a single object rather than a list of objects, and your DbSet is also written as a singular word `vwEntity`.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft LINQ fails to return any results when querying the object, it's just an empty list.

Comment: When I materialize the view with ToList(), I am unable to successfully use LINQ on it anymore and it just returns and empty list

Comment: Something else is going on.  Perhaps the `deal_status` is lower case and the database is using a case-insensitive collation?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft no, if I simply use var vwEntityList = dc.vwEntity.AsQueryable() it works, just a bit slow though for what i'm doing

Comment: well if you have items in vwEntityList, then there should not be a problem in a simple Where clause! make sure list do have items you trying to find.

Comment: `dc.vwEntity.AsQueryable()` doesn't load the data into memory. Any subsequent LINQ query will be translated to SQL and go back to the database.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft yes, this is what I'm trying to avoid. How can I load it into memory in a way I can successfully query it?

Comment: make your code to: `var vwEntityList = dc.vwEntity.ToList();`
`var newlist = vwEntityList.Where(x => x.deal_status == "B").ToList();` and put a break point to first make sure that _vwEntityList_ do have records you are finding then see if new list got populated.

Comment: @RashidAli I've been trying this, but thank you for your help! :) vwEntityList has a count of 200,000, but the new list is not populated when I know for sure that it should be! unless there is something about EF I don't understand.

Comment: Try to create an isolated repro and add it to your question.  What @RashidAli suggested should definitely work.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you've provided it sounds like this works (but is too slow for your liking)

```
var list = context.vwEntity.Where(x => x.deal_status == "B").ToList();
```

but this does not:

```
var totalList = context.vwEntity.ToList();
var list = totalList.Where(x => x.deal_status == "B").ToList();
```

The reason this would be the case is database collation. Some database such as SQL Server use a case-insensitive comparison for strings by default. So if a record had a deal_status of "b", then the first query would return that record because in SQL "B" == "b", however once loaded into memory, a Linq2Object where clause will do a case-sensitive comparison. "B" <> "b". SQL Server databases can be configured with case sensitive collations, so it is dangerous to assume strings will always be treated case-insensitive.

Linq expressions work against `IEnumerable` so you don't need to force a List back to `IQueryable`.

If you are working with Linq2Object, or against a case-sensitive database you should ensure case-insensitive matching is done where you want rather than relying on collation:

```
// this should work...
var totalList = context.vwEntity.ToList();
var list = totalList.Where(x => x.deal_status.ToUpper() == "B").ToList();
```

That said, reading an entire table/view into memory then querying against the objects should never really be "faster" than querying the entities unless perhaps you need to do a lot of different queries and want to cache the table in memory. Querying across strings can commonly hit performance snags if the fields being queried are not indexed.  I would suggest getting familiar with a query profiler for whatever database you are running against to capture the exact queries that EF is executing to identify performance bottlenecks. When facing slow queries, I don't think I've ever recommended "load the entire 200k records into memory first" as a solution. :)